# Query needed to retrive all the rows from one table joined with other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, message, and user. I want a query that retrieves all the rows from the massage table, irrespective of the value of the `user_id` field `NULL`.

message table:

```
id,      msg_date,       sms_text,  contact_id, user_id
'1',     '2019-04-09 ',  'Hello 1',    '1',       '1'
'2',     '2019-04-10',   'Hello 2',    '1',       NULL
'3',     '2019-04-11',   'Hello 3',    '1',       '1'
```

user table:

```
# user_id, fullname
'1',       'Manish Sijaria'
```

if i execute the below query. it does not return row `2` from message table.

```
SELECT id, message_date , msg_from, msg_to, sms_text, contact_id, 
       message.user_id, user.fullname  
FROM message left join user on message.user_id=user.user_id 
                               and message.contact_id=1;
```

Result of above query:-

```
id,   message_date,   sms_text, contact_id, user_id, fullname
'1',  '2019-04-09',   'Hello 1',  '1',       '1',    'Manish Sijaria'
'3',  '2019-04-11 ',  'Hello 3',  '1',       '1',    'Manish Sijaria'
```

Row `2` is missing as `user_id` is `NULL`.

But I want the rows with `user_id=NULL` from message table as well.
I want the  below result:-

```
id,   message_date,   sms_text, contact_id, user_id, fullname
'1',  '2019-04-09',   'Hello 1',  '1',       '1',     'Manish Sijaria'
'2',  '2019-04-10 ',  'Hello 2',  '1',       NULL,     NULL
'3',  '2019-04-11 ',  'Hello 3',  '1',       '1',     'Manish Sijaria'
```

Kindly Suggest the query in Mysql.

Comment: Your query looks fine and is returning expected result for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can perform full outer join to get all the values 
please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

so your query should be

```
SELECT id, message_date , msg_from, msg_to, sms_text, contact_id, 
       message.user_id, user.fullname  
FROM message left join user on message.user_id=user.user_id 
                               and message.contact_id=1
UNION ALL
 SELECT id, message_date , msg_from, msg_to, sms_text, contact_id, 
       message.user_id, user.fullname  
FROM message right join user on message.user_id=user.user_id 
                               and message.contact_id=1 and message.user_id is null
```

please also take  a look at this pic [image]

Comment: We do not need the second part of the query, first part itself will return the expected result

Comment: the first part will not return the values of message.user_id is null

Comment: yes, the union query returned the expected result. Thanks Moneer ji.